# Split a string via double occurances and single occurances of the number 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, frontend

I'm trying to split a string if the character 1 occurs twice or once.  Also, I'm only using the 1s and 2s.  Furthermore, the order must depend on the following example:

var str = "111221";

I want strArr=["1","11", "2" ,"2", "1"];

str.match(/1{2}|2|1{1}/g) will return [ '11', '1', '2', '2', '1' ]. However, this isn't in the right order. i.e.) 5 1s '11111' -> ['1','11','11'] and 6 1s '111111' -> ['11','11','11']

Comment: You want `1` then `11` ? Why don't you want `11` then `1` ?? Maybe you don't know what you want.

Comment: I want this ordered 1 then 11 so that I can map this through an object which will return it in order

Comment: And should `'111111'` become `['11', '11', '11]` or `['11, '1', '11', '1']` or `['1', '1', '1', '11', '1']`, or...?

Comment: Or, what is it about that stuff ?

Comment: @ScottSauyet ['11','11','11']  i.e)  five 1s would give '11111' -> ['1','11','11']

Comment: What about the `2`'s ??

Comment: @sin The 2 is just put in the array as "2"... duplicates don't matter

Comment: How should `1111` be broken down ? `1`,`1`,`11` ?

Comment: @sin ["11","11"]

Comment: It is not clear at all what splitting algorithm you're after.

Comment: @jfriend00  - Are you fixated on the word _split_ ? split is totally useless, invented back in bsd days I'm sure.

Comment: @sln - No.  I simply did not understand what the desired algorithm was to create the output.  It was an unclear question to me.  I was using split as a generic term.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I would say for JS, regex is crippled (for now). In any language, _split_ almost never is appropriate except for the simplest of one direction logic. That simplicity is never the case when someone wants to match a complexity.

Comment: @sln - I used the phrase `split` in the generic sense in that the OP asked to split the output from a single string into multiple strings.  See http://www.dictionary.com/browse/split?s=t if you're confused about that.  First definition: "to divide or separate from end to end or into layers".  Fourth definition: "to divide into distinct parts or portions".  I simply found the question unclear (as did others judging by the downvotes on the question).

Comment: @jfriend00 - Yeah, I see that. I don't penalize for not being %100 correct in the wording of their question. Hell, they're nervous enough as it is. _Conceptual_ errors get me though, I'm a dog on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with this.

`(?:1(?=(?:11)*(?!1))|11|2)`

It basically just gets the first *odd* 1, then gets evens.

https://regex101.com/r/UtbhsV/1

Explained

```
 (?:
      1                   # First, try 1
      (?=                 # Must be followed by even amount of 1's
           (?: 11 )*
           (?! 1 )
      )
   |  11                  # Or, only even's left, just get 11
   |  2                   # Or, How about a  2 ?
 )
```

Comment: Can you use this to convert `"111221"` into `["1","11", "2" ,"2", "1"]`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet -  Sure can.`(?:1(?:(?=(?:11)*(?!1)))|11|2)` https://regex101.com/r/TkHOWP/1

Comment: Very nice!  I was doing it without regex, and it turned ugly!